# adding a twitch username to my alert effect code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an effect for twitch subscribers that 'decodes' the text, but instead of saying "[username] just subscribed" it says "just subscribed"... how would I make the username appear (I have code that works without the effect), also, I need to know how to make the message decode itself as well.

html:

```
<div class="text-container">
    <div>
        <div class="awsome-text-container">
          <span id="username-container"></span>
          <span class="code" role="content">
          Just Subscribed
          </span>
        </div>
        <p>
            {{message}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
@import url('https://cdn.streamelements.com/scripts/animate.min.css');
* {
    font-family: 'monospace';
}

.awsome-text-container {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text-container {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

$background: #263238;
span{
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: 'monospace' ;
  font-size: 70px ;
  font-size: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
//get data from the  StreamElements  data injection
const name = '{{name}}';

// vanilla es6 query selection (can use libraries and frameworks too)
const userNameContainer = document.querySelector('#username-container');

var toString = $('.code').html()
var OGarray = toString.split('');
var genNum
var counter = 0
var cutOffAt = 55
var obfuscated = 1

function getRandom(len) {
  return new Array(len + 1).join('2');

}

function Gen() {
  var length = toString.length;
  console.log(length)
  genNum = getRandom(length);
  console.log(genNum)

  $('.letters').html(genNum);
  console.log(genNum)
}

function parser(NUarray) {
  $.each(NUarray, function(index, value) {
    if (value == 0) {
      NUarray[index] = OGarray[index]
    } else if (value == OGarray[index]) {
      NUarray[index] = OGarray[index]
    } else if (isNaN(value)) {
      NUarray[index] = OGarray[index]
    } else {
      change = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
      NUarray[index] = change
    }
  });
  if (NUarray.toString() == OGarray.toString()) {
    obfuscated = 0
    window.clearInterval(interval)
  }
  if (counter == 50) {
    obfuscated = 0
    window.clearInterval(interval)
    NUarray = OGarray

  }
  counter += 1
  return NUarray.join("")

}

function Genletters(stringToChange) {
  var string = stringToChange.toString().split('')
  return genNum = parser(string)
}

function runThis() {
  Genletters(genNum)
  console.log(genNum)
  $('.code').html(genNum)
}
Gen();
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  runThis();
}, 100);
```

the code that supposedly makes the username appear is `<span id="username-container"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Try not closing the span before the "Just Subscribed" message, so, try this code:

```
        <div class="awsome-text-container">
          <span id="username-container">
          <span class="code" role="content">
          Just Subscribed
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
```